# MQTT Configuration File Mosquitto on Azure Ubunutu VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-the-mosquitto-mqtt-messaging-broker-on-ubuntu-18-04#prerequisites) to configure mosquitto.

This means that I'm storing my local configuration in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf`. However, I've just now realized that I can put any password/username and it will access mosquitto meaning my config file isn't taken into account. I've just now discovered the `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` and its content can be seen below:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

The contents of my configuration file that I want to use `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf` can be seen below.

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 1883

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/20.56.xxx.xxx/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/20.56.xxx.xxx/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/20.56.xxx.xxx/privkey.pem
```

Using the command `sudo pkill mosquitto` and then `sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d -d` I stopped mosquitto and restarted it in the background running the new configuration file. When I first ran it (using the `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf` shown above), I got the `Error: Connection Refused`. I then modified the `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf` file, killed mosquitto and ran it again using the same techinque. The new config file can be seen below.

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 1883
```

For this version, the password and username protection works!!

Here are the logs for those operations

```
1610537764: mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:42:22 -0300) starting
1610537764: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1610537764: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1610537764: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1610537764: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1610537764: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1610537764: Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/20.56.121.212/chain.pem".
1610537909: mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:42:22 -0300) starting
1610537909: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1610537909: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1610537909: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1610537909: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1610537909: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1610537912: New connection from xx.xx.2.13 on port 1883.
1610537912: New client connected from xx.xx.2.13 as mqtt_f1f0a02.f7e396 (c1, k60, u'bigBoiTeam').
1610538010: mosquitto version 1.4.15 terminating
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read and impossible for people using screen readers

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65690500/edit) the question to show what you've put in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf` so we can see what you expect to happen.

Comment: OK, the `default.conf` looks fine, assuming you restarted mosquitto after making the edits it should be reading it. The way to know is to check the logs to see if it's starting the port 8883 listener

Comment: I've indeed restarted mosquitto after the edits. I'm new to all this and don't how to check the logs but  I've tried connecting to it from my web app and it doesn't work. Furthermore, I'm able to pub and sub form my web app to the broker with an invalide/inexistent username and/or password meaning it doesn't take  `allow_anonymous false` into account right? Could the problem be that I need to modifify `include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d'` to `include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf`? Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: *(I don't want to messup mosquitto by editing what I shouldn't as my teammates are using the broker to test their systems)

Comment: No, the `include_dir` points to a directory (clue is in the name) not a file. The log file is clearly listed in the `mosquitto.conf` file

Comment: That log clearly shows the `default.conf` has not been read (no port 8883 listener started)

Comment: Yeah, I see now. How does mosquitto choose the configuration file located in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/` though? Because there could be multiple .conf files so do I not need to specify which one to use?

Comment: It loads all of them, please have a look at the `mosquitto.conf` man oage

Comment: Didn't that before.. It does load all of them in alphabetical order indeed. However it still doesn't seem to read my default.conf file. Even after I've tried adding a "/" at the end of `include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d` in `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: I've now seen this question https://superuser.com/questions/998381/mosquitto-broker-running-with-wrong-conf-file-at-boot. I checked `/etc/init.d/mosquitto` and it does appear that mosquitto goes to get the .conf in `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` as it should.. I'm not sure what to try next :/

Comment: The logs show you STILL have another copy of mosquitto running and the service is NOT starting using the config file

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help, I'm fairly new to all this! The passwords finally work. I just have to work on the SSL now. Cheers again!